# Extract column based on value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can i extract only the column with only have 1 data in , separated by :

```
demo@example.com:bo:mo
demo1@example.com::
demo2@example.com::
```

desired output

```
demo1@example.com::
demo2@example.com::
```

my last command try

```
sed "${var%%::*}::"
```

Comment: you mean whose all fields are empty apart from 1st field? Please clarify more on this.

Comment: yes RavinderSingh13 thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i){count++}};if(count==1){print};count=""}'  Input_file
```

OR in a different form with same logic.

```
awk -F":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){count=$i?++count:count}} count==1{print} {count=""}' Input_file
```

Comment: @DOWN VOTER, please do let me know the reason of down vote??

Answer (score 0):

Ah - from the comments, I infer, that all fields shall be empty, except the first one. Then even simpler:

```
echo "demo@example.com:bo:mo
demo1@example.com:bo:
demo2@example.com::" | sed -n "/::/p"
```

sed -n means 'no printing by default'. /::/ is the pattern to find, the 'p' means print, if the pattern was matched.

To just print the content of the first column:

```
echo "demo@example.com:bo:mo
demo1@example.com:bo:
demo2@example.com::" | sed -rn "s/(.*)::/\1/p"
demo2@example.com
```

-r means 'extended regex', here important for the round braces which capture everything before the colons. \1 is the backreference to print.